# MS Excel: Counting Right to Left Based on Criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

and thank you in advance for any help you can provide.
Background:  I am trying to count how many metrics had a "R" (Red) value continuously until the value was changed to "A" (Amber) or "G" (Green).

I want to create a function that can count when the value is "R" from right to left until it changes.  If the first cell is not "R" then it returns 0.

Example 1 below, cell {Jul-22} should return "3" since there are 3 "R" from where the function is inserted.
[Example1 - 3 Red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPJCy.png)

Example 2 below, cell {Jul-22} should return "1" since there is 1 "R" from where the function is inserted.
[Example 2 - 1 Red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2isxj.png)

Example 3 below, cell {Jul-22} should return "0" since there is 0 "R" from where the function is inserted.
[Example 3 - 0 Red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyJTP.png)

Example 4 below, cell {Jul-22} should return "8" since there is 8 "R" from where the function is inserted.
[Example 4 - 8 Red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3ppT.png)

I have attempted using Power Query and COUNTIF with OFFSET.  I feel that COUNTIF/OFFSET limits me from starting my count left to right, which I don't want to do.  I am also having trouble counting text values using COUNTIF/OFFSET, so I tried to first convert the R-A-G using a basic IF/THEN statement to return "R" as 1 and the rest as 0.

Sometimes using the COUNTIF/OFFSET function I get a "Volatile" error message.

Below is an example of the function I tried and the table used.
Cell A2 contains this function "=COUNTIF(OFFSET(A2,0,1,MATCH(0,B2:V2,0)),"<>0")"
Cells B2 --> V2 contain this function respectively "=IF(OR(B1="G",B1="A"),0,1)"

[COUNTIF/OFFSET Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwxDD.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following formula will give the result and with the two changeable values at the very beginning makes changing its parameters easy:

```
=LET(Range,  B2:M2,  CountValue,  "R",  Columns,  COLUMNS(Range),  Number,  SEQUENCE(1,Columns,Columns,-1),
      String,  MID(TEXTJOIN("",FALSE,  INDEX(Range,1,Number)  ),1,Number),
      ComparisonString,  MID(REPT(CountValue,Columns),1,SEQUENCE(1,Columns,Columns,-1)),

      SUM(  IF(  String=ComparisonString,  1,  0)  )
      )
```

It looks more daunting, yes, but then handles whatever the range and letter to count might need to be.

The trick is getting the cells in reverse order. (I used the old one with `INDEX` so it fits more versions of Excel for you, but one can change that out.) After that it just bludgeons the checking for immediate and contiguous values needing counting by comparing the range's various length strings to equal length versions made from the `REPT` function's string of "however many" cells in the range that there are. Increase the range length to 100 columns and it will form strings of one to one hundred R's. No cleverness in that, but it works. If one had longer strings to check, not only might it fail if they came in varying sizes, but even with same sizes for all cells, the strings formed might begin to pass the maximum string length for the functions and cut the strings off, risking incorrect results. But with just one letter and the comma between each string, and the arithmetically increasing lengths as the range enlarges... well, that might happen anyway, but far sooner with, say, four letter characters in each cell so multiplying the above by four.

So it has features one might see as advantageous (I do), but there are risks, and therefore limits, to it.

Comment: This worked great, thanks so much Jeorje.

Answer (score 0):

If the column width isn't too much, then you could nest a bunch of IF statements:

```
=IF(L2<>"R",0,IF(K2<>"R",1,IF(J2<>"R",2,IF(I2<>"R",3,IF(H2<>"R",4,IF(G2<>"R",5,IF(F2<>"R",6,IF(E2<>"R",7,IF(D2<>"R",8,IF(C2<>"R",9,IF(B2<>"R",10,"check")))))))))))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will try this out.  However, the columns will increase by one each month.